# spring-data-jdbc dependency won't work on pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, spring-data-jdbc

I'm following this guide [spring-data-jdbc-ext](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jdbc-ext/)

and i'm trying to set this dependency on my pom.xml

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.M2</version>
 </dependency>`

but i ended up on this error

> No such file or directory found on the repository using this maven dependency (provided on the quick start guide).

I'm using Maven version 4.0.0

Comment: this artifact is not available on maven central. You need to add Spring repository to get this artifact.

Comment: Please note that Spring Data JDBC (https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jdbc/) and Spring Data JDBC Extensions are two different projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this repository to your pom:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. @Iohnns comment cleared my confusion on this.

Comment: @TheHeadRush there's a timer before i can do that. don't rush child.

Comment: It's my nature. Sorry.